# Return type of get Class method is different from actual returntype

Tags: java, object, generics, wildcard, return-type

When I created a instance of a class A and tried to access its getClass() method, its return type is different than what is mentioned in java Object class.

```
A a = new A() ;
Class<? extends A> clazz = a.getClass();
```

Even when I access the getClass method as mentioned above in Intellij, it says its return type is `Class<? extends A>` and even the java doc says it returns wildcard extends  upper bound. I can totally accept it. Because I can create instance of B and reference to A and access getClass method.

But why does the return type of the getClass method is just`Class<?>` in the Object class

Edit 1 (After the comment from Andy Turner)

```
Class A {
   List<?> returningNullList() {
     return null;
   } 
}
```

When I create a instance of A , and tried to access returningNullList () method, it didn't give me return type as `List<? extends A>`. But when I tried to access getClass method it says return type is `Class<? extends A>` although the actual hard-coded return type is `Class<? >` in Object.java file

Is the getClass method is treated specially by compiler?

Comment: I can't parse your last sentence. Can you reword it, or add an example to show what you mean?

Comment: In Object class file, I can see return type is just UNBOUNDED wildcard

Comment: Also reworded last sentence

Comment: "it didn't give me return type as `List<? extends A>`" that's because `A` isn't the upper bound of the type variable. It's `Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the *documentation*, i.e. the javadoc of [`getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) in class `Object`:

> **The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is called.** For example, no cast is required in this code fragment:
>
> ```java
> Number n = 0;
> Class<? extends Number> c = n.getClass();
> ```

<sup>*The bolding is from the javadoc, not added by me.*</sup>

For class `Object` itself, it means that the return type is `Class<? extends Object>`, but since `Class<?>` is shorthand for `Class<? extends Object>`, the javadoc simply shows the shorthand.

Quoting the Java Language Specification, section [4.5.1. Type Arguments of Parameterized Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1):

> The wildcard `? extends Object` is equivalent to the unbounded wildcard `?`.

Answer (score 3):

> But why does the return type of the getClass method is just`Class<?>` in the Object class

`Class<?>` is the same as `Class<? extends Object>`, because all classes (except `Object`) have `Object` as a superclass. There's no reason to include that bound explicitly.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you check the edit section once?

Comment: Also the java doc says, the actual result type will include upper bound, although the signature of the method doesn't have it.